# How to Re-Initiate the child component in vueJs 3?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I need to change the values and re-initiate the component with props Data.
i tried with `$emit` unfortunately doesn't work my code.

> chart.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header header-elements">
                <div>
                    <h5 class="card-title mb-0">Statistics</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-header-elements ms-auto py-0">
                    <select name="status" class="form-select form-select-sm" v-model="chartType" @click="$emit('someEvent')">
                        <option value="daily" data-label="Days">Last 7 Days</option>
                        <option value="weekly" data-label="Weeks">Weekly</option>
                        <option value="monthly" data-label="Months">Monthly</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <line-chart v-bind:chartData="chartData" v-bind:chartOptions="chartOptions" v-if="showLineGraph"  @some-event="chartData"></line-chart>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: {},
    mounted() {
    },
    created(){
        this.params.params = {
            chart_type: "daily",
        };
        this.chartOptions.scales.xAxes[0].scaleLabel.display = "DAYS";
        this.chartOptions.scales.xAxes[0].scaleLabel.labelString = "DAYS";
        this.loadGraph();
    },
    data() {
        return {
            chartType:'daily',
            showLineGraph:false,
            params: {
                params: {}
            },
            datasetSample: {
                data: [],
                label: "",
                borderColor: "#ff5b5c",
                tension: 0.5,
                pointStyle: "circle",
                backgroundColor: "#ff5b5c",
                fill: false,
                pointRadius: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 5,
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 5,
                pointBorderColor: "transparent",
                pointHoverBorderColor: "#fff",
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#ff5b5c",
                height: 500
            },
            chartData: {
                labels: [],
                datasets: []
            },
            chartOptions: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: "",
                                labelString: ""
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                display: true,
                            },
                        }],
                    yAxes: [{
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            scaleLabel: {
                                display: "Amount In INR",
                                labelString: "Amount In INR"
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                display: true,
                            },
                            ticks: {
                                maxTicksLimit: 10,
                                beginAtZero: false,
                                callback: function (value, index, values) {
                                    return value.toLocaleString();
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                },
                legend: {
                    position: 'top',
                    align: 'start',
                    labels: {
                        usePointStyle: true,
                        padding: 15,
                        boxWidth: 6,
                        boxHeight: 6,
                    }
                },
                plugins: {
                    tooltip: {
                        // Updated default tooltip UI
                        backgroundColor: "#fff",
                        titleColor: "#000",
                        bodyColor: "#000",
                        borderWidth: 1,
                        borderColor: "#0560e8"
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    },
    methods: {
        loadGraph: function () {
            this.chartData.datasets=[];
            this.chartData.labels = [];
            

            axios.get(window.location.href + "/get-chart-data", this.params)
                .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data);
                if (response.data.status == 200) {
                    let datasets = response.data.data.datasets;
                    let chart_vlaues=[];
                    
                    for (var key in datasets) {
                        if (datasets.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                            let temp_dataset = Object.assign({}, this.datasetSample);

                            temp_dataset.data = datasets[key].values;
                            temp_dataset.label = key;
                            temp_dataset.borderColor = datasets[key].colour;
                            temp_dataset.backgroundColor = datasets[key].colour;
                            temp_dataset.pointHoverBackgroundColor = datasets[key].colour;

                            chart_vlaues.push(temp_dataset);
                        }
                    }
                    
                    this.chartData.datasets=chart_vlaues;
                    this.chartData.labels = response.data.data.labels;
                    this.showLineGraph=true;
                    
                }else {
                    this.chartData.datasets = [];
                    this.chartData.labels = [];
                    this.showLineGraph = true;
                }
            })
                .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                console.log("Chart could not loaded.");
            })
                .then(() => {
            });
        },

    }
}
</script>
```

> LineChart.Vue

```
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend,Line} from 'vue3-chart-v2'

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'LineChart',
  extends: Line,Tooltip,Legend,Title,
  props: {
    chartData: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    },
    chartOptions: {
      type: Object,
      required: false
    },
  },
  watch : {
    someEvent: function (value) {
      console.log('from watch');
    }
  },
  mounted () {},
  created(){
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.chartOptions);
  },
  data(){
  },
  methods:{
    someEvent:function(){
      alert('iiiiiiiiii');
    }
  },
  emits: {
    someEvent(payload) {
      console.log('some emits');
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

> app.js

```
require('./bootstrap')


import { createApp } from 'vue'

import lineChart from './components/lineChart';
import chart from './components/chart.vue';


const app = createApp({})

app.component('chart', chart);
app.component('line-chart', lineChart);
          
app.mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0):

You use watchers wrong. They are not for watching events.

```
 watch : {
    someEvent: function (value) {
      console.log('from watch');
    }
  },
```

You also did not define your custom event with `emits`

Please, check the Vue docs about the [Component Events](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#component-events)

The typical data flow with Vue components is

to the Component: `App -> Data -> Component Props -> Watchers -> Methods`

from The component: `Data -> Event -> Event Handler -> App`

So, if you want to re-initiate your child component, that you should update some child component's prop and then react to the change in some child component's watcher.